# How to switch Kubernetes contexts with multiple config files?

Tags: kubernetes

```
KUBECONFIG="$(find ~/.kube/configs/ -type f -exec printf '%s:' '{}' +)"
```

This will construct a config file path for the environment var. I can see the contexts of my clusters and I can switch them. However when I want to get my nodes I get

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

How to solve, any ideas?

Comment: check the output of ```echo $KUBECONFIG ``` .

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you either don't have a `current-context` set or your `current-context` points to a non-functioning cluster.

If set (or exported) `KUBECONFIG` can reference a set of config files.

The files' content will be merged. I think this is what you're attempting.

But then, that variable must be exported for `kubectl` to use.

Either:

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=...
kubectl ...
```

Or:

```sh
KUBECONFIG=... kubectl ...
```

Then, you can:

```sh
# List contexts by NAME
kubectl config get-contexts

# Use one of them by NAME
kubectl config use-context ${NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this function:

```
function change-cluster () {

    export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/configs/"$1"-kubeconfig
    kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@"$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command will give you the list of kubernetes context exist in your server
kubectl config get-contexts

to switch to the particular context below command can be used
kubectl config use-context <context_name>

To use multiple config file you can create temp merged config file & then use the above commands